# Laravel Model Binding missing relationships

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent, model-binding, laravel-5

I'm trying to convert to Model binding on a Model built on customer orders. My route:

```
Route::model('order', 'App\Models\Order');
Route::resource('orders', 'OrderController');
```

This allows me to pull up an Order to edit through my controller (also grabbing statuses to populate a table and passing the logged in user):

```
public function index(Order $order)
 {
  $orders = $order->get();
  return view('orders.index', compact('orders'));
}
```

My orders.index will display $order->id properly but when I try to loop through the Actions, which is connected by a hasMany relationship, nothing shows. Or I try to show $order->user->firstname which belongs to User by user_id.

```
@foreach( $order->actions as $action )
  {{ $action->type->type }}
@endforeach
```

From my Action model:

```
public function order()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\Order', 'order_id');
}
```

From my Order model:

```
public function actions()
{
    return $this->hasMany('\App\Models\Action', 'order_id');
}
```

Here's an excerpt from a dump of the Order:

```
`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => App\Models\Order Object
                (
                    [table:protected] => orders
                    [timestamps] => 1
                    [dates:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => deleted_at
                        )

                    [connection:protected] => 
                    [primaryKey:protected] => id
                    [perPage:protected] => 15
                    [incrementing] => 1
                    [attributes:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [created_at] => 2015-03-16 23:42:45
                            [updated_at] => 2015-03-19 04:37:53
                            [deleted_at] => 
                            [user_id] => 16
                            [status_id] => 5
                            [address_id] => 5
                            [datetime_pickup_actual] => 
                            [datetime_delivery_actual] => 
                            [datetime_pickup_requested] => 2015-03-20 17:00:00
                            [datetime_delivery_requested] => 2015-03-21 17:00:00
                            [hold] => 0
                            [weight] => 20
                        )

                    [original:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [created_at] => 2015-03-16 23:42:45
                            [updated_at] => 2015-03-19 04:37:53
                            [deleted_at] => 
                            [user_id] => 16
                            [status_id] => 5
                            [address_id] => 5
                            [datetime_pickup_actual] => 
                            [datetime_delivery_actual] => 
                            [datetime_pickup_requested] => 2015-03-20 17:00:00
                            [datetime_delivery_requested] => 2015-03-21 17:00:00
                            [hold] => 0
                            [weight] => 20
                        )

                    [relations:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [hidden:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [visible:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [appends:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [fillable:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [guarded:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => *
                        )

                    [casts:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [touches:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [observables:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [with:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [morphClass:protected] => 
                    [exists] => 1
                    [forceDeleting:protected] => 
                )`
```

Answer (score 1):

As you compact `orders` in your controller you should use `orders` in your `Blade` template:

```
@foreach( $orders->actions as $action )
  {{ $action->type->type }}
@endforeach
```

You should be also aware that `Order` in your `index` method in controller have nothing in common with Route Model Binding. For `index` it won't be used at all.

For other methods (show/edit/delete) it won't work because you make a binding with wrong name. It should be:

```
Route::model('orders', 'App\Models\Order');
```

and not

```
Route::model('order', 'App\Models\Order');
```

Answer (score 0):

Model name (MoneyEntry)

Changed from

```
Route::resource('moneyentries', 'MoneyEntryController');
```

to

```
Route::resource('moneyEntries', 'MoneyEntryController');
```

Did a trick.